# Replacing a character in a string (char array) with multiple characters in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

C is not a managed language, and it's been a while since I have used an unmanaged language.  I need to create a block of code which searches through a character array, and replaces all instances of '2' with 'Ba'.  This is quite simple, except for the fact that now the resulting string will be larger than the original, so I need to account for this somehow, and I don't remember how to do this.

Here is try number 4, using pointers:

```
//Move next 150 characters after replacing all 2 with Ba:
    numberread = read(XYZFile, datatoreadWWW, sizeof(datatoreadWWW));
    int y = strlen(datatoreadWWW); //should be 150.
    int additionallength = y;
    i = 0;
    while(i < y) {
      if(datatoreadWWW[i] == '2') {
        additionallength++; //Since we need to replace any '2' with 'Ba', we should add one character for the a.
      }
      i++;
    }
    //And now use additionallength to create the new char array to be placed in WWW, called newstring:
    char newstring[additionallength];
    int j = 0;
    const char *in = datatoreadWWW;
    char *out = newstring;
    while(*in) {
      if (*in == '2') {
    *out++ = 'B';
    *out++ = 'a';
      }
      else {
    *out++ = *in;
      }
      in++;
    }
    *out++ = '\0';
```

And I'm still confused/stuck on this, I'm getting garbage values written into the WWW file such as "^Q" and such.  Not sure what that means, but it doesn't seem correct.

**Edit:** The program above seems to be working now.  The problem was, if anyone ever reads this post as a resource, that I was adding +1 to additionallength, but this was happening in every iteration, so every so many characters there was an extra empty, null space being put in to the file, which was incorrect.  Regardless, I think we've learned that is important to review pointers whenever working in C, as this is the easiest way to accomplish this.

Comment: "managed" or "unmanaged" has nothing to do with this. I think you are referring to the lack of a standard container with an insert operation.

Comment: `'Ba'` is a *multi-byte character constant* , it is still a single character after all that. What you actually want is two characters, `'B'` and `'a'`. As you say, you need to have enough space because the result will be larger than the original. Try writing some code and then posting it.

Comment: K Matt, hold on I'm working on it!

Comment: C _is_ a managed language, it's just the developer (rather than the runtime) doing the management :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

- Compute the length of the new array by adding the number of `'2'`s to `strlen` of your string plus one for null terminator
- Allocate the required number of `char`s using `malloc`
- Go through your string in a loop; if you see `'2'`, add `'B'` followed by `'a'` to the output;
- Otherwise, copy the current character to the output.

Note: now that your string is allocated dynamically, you need to call `free` once you are done using it.

```
const char* str = ...
int cnt = strlen(str)+1;
for (const char *p = str ; *p ; cnt += (*p++ == '2'))
    ;
char *res = malloc(cnt);
char *out = res;
const char *in = str;
while (*in) {
    if (*in == '2') {
        *out++ = 'B';
        *out++ = 'a';
    } else {
        *out++ = *in;
    }
    in++;
}
*out++ = '\0';
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/dJ3eOe)

Comment: Or, if you don't want to loop over the string twice, you could optimistically pre-allocate a buffer that is only “somewhat” larger than the input and `realloc()`ate it if it turns out that it was too short.

Comment: Can this be accomplished without making any allocation calls?  I simply created a new character array with size of the original, plus the amount of 2s that were present, plus 1 for the null terminator.

Comment: @Musicode That would work, too, as long as the result is used within the same function. Replace the `malloc` line with `char res[cnt];`, and the code would continue to work.

Comment: @Musicode You forgot the last line (adding null terminator).

Comment: How do I add the null terminator to the end of a character array?  Just place '\0' at strlen[example_array] ?

Comment: @Musicode Your last attempt is incorrect in other ways, too: you try to use a single index `j` instead of two pointers `in` and `out` in my example. That is why your code skips over some characters, leaving gaps. If you do not like pointers, use indexes; it's all the same. Once the loop is over, put `'\0'` in the character at your writing index.

Comment: Yes, I see what you are mentioning now.  I don't like pointers, at least not yet (I just started C again today after a 2 year hiatus, so I'm quite bad), so I'll have to try a method using only indices and update my post with trial 4.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the solutions are excessively complex, pointlessly verbose, and are inefficient (e.g., strlen means three scans when only two are needed).

```
int newlen = 1;

for (char* p = str; *p; p++)
    newlen += *p == '2' ? 2 : 1;

char newstr[newlen];

for (char *p = str, *q = newstr;; p++)
    if (*p == '2')
    {
        *q++ = 'B';
        *q++ = 'a';
    }
    else if (!(*q++ = *p))
        break;
```

Comment: I tried this method but I am now getting garbage values in my WWW file that I am writing to...

Comment: `char newstr[newlen];` is not legal C, use `char * newstr = malloc(newlen);`

Comment: @Musicode Perhaps you're writing it incorrectly, or perhaps your input is garbled.. I notice that you're using `read` ... that's not a good idea and doesn't NUL-terminate the input. Use stdio.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea how to do this:

- **count the number of '2's** in your char array and store in a variable, let's say `count`.
- create a new char array, let's say `new_word`, with the **size of your previous char array plus the number of 2's** stored in the `count` variable.
- iterate from the end of your input word, storing the characters in the `new_word`. Each time you reach a '2', you insert 'a', then 'B', and of course, update the indexes properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this also..

```
main()
{
char a[]="abcabcabcabcabcabcabc";
char *p;
int i=0,c=0;

for(i=0;a[i];i++)
if(a[i]=='c')
c++;

printf("c=%d\n",c);
p=calloc(sizeof(a)+c,1);

for(i=0;a[i];i++)
{
static int j=0;
if(a[i]=='c')
    {
    *(p+j++)='n';
    *(p+j++)='s';
    }
 else
    {
    *(p+j++)=a[i];
    }
   }
   printf("%s\n",p);
  }
```